# Andengine Touch Event for Entity

Tags: events, touch, entity, andengine

I need to add a touch event to some classes that extend the Entity class, but it doesn't seem to work.

Doing this for Sprites, AnimatedSprites and primitives works like a charm just by doing something like:

```
Sprite s = new Sprite(...){
    public boolean onAreaTouched(...){
           ...
    return true;
    }
}
registerTouchArea(s);
```

But this does not work when applied to an entity or a class that extends Entity.

Do you know what it should be done in this case?
Is it even possible to use onAreaTouched on an Entity class? If no, what would be a work around?

Please help

Answer (score 0):

It's so easy. Follow below code

Make a Example Entity. Code is self Descriptive.

```
public class Example extends Entity implements IOnAreaTouchListener {

    public Rectangle aSprite;

    public Example(float pX, float pY,
            VertexBufferObjectManager pVertexBufferObjectManager) {

        // initialize  your sprite  & it's touch implementation
        aSprite = new Rectangle(pX, pY, 40, 40, pVertexBufferObjectManager) {

            @Override
            public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
                    float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {

                if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionUp()) {
                    Log.e("Rectangle aSprite", "isActionUp");
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        };

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttached() {

        super.onAttached();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
            ITouchArea pTouchArea, float pTouchAreaLocalX,
            float pTouchAreaLocalY) {


        aSprite.onAreaTouched(pSceneTouchEvent, pTouchAreaLocalX,
                pTouchAreaLocalY);

        return false;
    }

}
```

In your **Custom Scene** class or your **onCreateScene**(),  write like that

```
    Example example = new Example(80, 80, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    mCurrentScene.attachChild(example.aSprite);
    mCurrentScene.registerTouchArea(example.aSprite);
```